# clang not generating debug symbols

Tags: clang, lldb

I have a `a.c`

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = a + b;
    return 0;
}
```

when compiling with `clang -g a.c`, I can't get debug symbols.

```
joey@voyager-arch /t/a4> lldb a.out
(lldb) target create "a.out"
Current executable set to '/tmp/a4/a.out' (x86_64).
(lldb) l
(lldb)
```

But if I use gcc, I can successfully got the debug symbols, compile with `gcc -g a.c`

```
joey@voyager-arch /t/a4> gdb a.out
GNU gdb (GDB) 11.1

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from a.out...
(gdb) l
1       #include <stdio.h>
2
3       int main() {
4               int a = 1;
5               int b = 2;
6               int c = a + b;
7               return 0;
8       }
(gdb)
```

I'm using archlinux with amd ryzen 7 cpu.

```
clang: 12.0.1
lldb: 12.0.1
gcc: 11.1.0
gdb: 11.1
```

Answer (score 0):

May be a lldb 12 incompatible bug, downgrade to lldb 10 solved this problem.